# Entity Framework Core -- does one need to check whether or not a query can ever return results

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
 public async Task<List<MyModel>> GetAllForIds(IList<Guid> ids) 
 {
    // query the database for entities which have a field that matches one of the ids,
    // then map those entities to models and return.
 }
```

If the list of ids is empty, obviously the query is not going to return anything, so one might as well not bother contacting the db. My question is whether or not EF Core is smart enough to figure that out on its own. If not, and if an empty list of ids is a possibility, I should change the above to read something like the following:

```
public async Task<List<MyModel>> GetAllForIds(IList<Guid> ids) 
{
    if (ids.Any()) 
    {
        // query the database for entities which have a field that matches one of the ids,
        // then map those entities to models and return.
    } 
    else 
    {
        return new List<MyModel>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent database roundtrips when it's sure no data will be returned you have to do it yourself.

EF core even removed some "smartness" in this area. In "classic" **EF6**, when executing a query like...

```cs
Products.Where(p => false)
```

...it is detected that the `Where` statement evaluates to `false` (even when that's a bit harder, and also with an empty collection in your case), and it sends a dummy query to the database. Something like:

```sql
SELECT 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C1], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C2], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C4], 
    CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C5], 
    ...
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    WHERE 1 = 0
```

So the database will hardly notice it. *But it's still a roundtrip*. I have no idea why EF6 does this while it seems smart enough to know it might as well return an empty `IQueryable` right away.

**EF-core** stopped sending this dummy query. It does detect that the predicate evaluates to `false`, but then it simply generates a query like:

```sql
SELECT [p].[Id], etc., etc.
FROM [Products] AS [p]
WHERE 0 = 1
```

I'm happy with that. All built-in smartness brings a risk of being too smart in specific cases that were overlooked until they pop up. I ask EF to execute a query and it does. Nice and simple.